# How to merge tesselating regions into larger ones?

Tags: computational-geometry

I have a map, which is broken into adjacent regions. Regions do not overlap. Regions are of complex shapes (they are administrative districts).

I want to display these regions on Google Map. But the problem is that the regions are of very different sizes. If zoom level fits largest regions into map frame, then there are numerous small regions, which overload the widget, but doesn't actual visible by user.

I would like to merge smaller regions into bigger ones by some reasonable algorithm.

Can you hint me onto some keywords?

Here is my proposed algorithm for now:

[image]

At each scale I am taking a grid. The grid is the same as grid of tiles google map uses, i.e. tile is 256 pixles wide, zoom level 0 means entire world in one tile.

For each region I am calculating a tile, to which center (center of tile) region's centroid ("center" of region) is closest.

If zoom is too small, small regions turn to belong to same tiles and
these are regions I merge. On picture occasionally there are no regions to merge because they are all assigned to different tiles.

Comment: I am not sure if this is an on topic question, someone more experienced could advise. However, you could compute the 'Union' of the polygons via the Vatti Clipping Algorithm (or others). The ['Clipper'](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php) library from Angus Johnson is a well known performant, open-source, implementation for general polygon clipping.

Comment: First come up with a heuristic solution (e.g., group together regions which map to the same point), and then figure out a fast way of implementing it.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus what do you mean "map to the same point"? Adjacent?

Comment: I mean regions that map to the same point under some zoom level. Perhaps instead of this kind of overlap, you should consider regions mapping to adjacent or very close points. It's up to you to decide – you're the needknower.

Comment: 1. What does "center region's center" mean?   Is that a typo?  2. You list your current proposed algorithm.  Why have you rejected it?  What is wrong with it?  What requirements does it fail to meet?

Comment: @D.W. I will use this algorithm; me myself don't see shorcomings, just put for peer review